# Get eZ Flow zones of an object

Tags: php, ezpublish, zeta-components

for a navigation on our site I need to fetch a specific zone and the included blocks from some objects in our eZ Publish installation.

Can you tell me how I can fetch the blocks in this zone?

I tried to inspect the whole object using attribute(show), but I only found this output by using

```
{$object.children[0].data_map.page.content.zones|attribute(show)}
```

Result

```
Attribute Type Value
0   object[eZPageZone]  Object
>id     string  'a52658c8b1d003bbbe6dc542108dd534'
>zone_identifier    string  'main'
1   object[eZPageZone]  Object
>id     string  '3893870da1d595349061a4bba3fd1be7'
>zone_identifier    string  'guide'
2   object[eZPageZone]  Object
>id     string  'f43306e22fb45f1ed72ce3b7276c39d9'
>zone_identifier    string  'keyvis'
```

Well, I got the zone ID ...

Is there a fetch to get the zone and the blocks behind this ID?

Comment: Two cents for readers : the question was also asked on the eZ Publish Community forums, where useful answers might have been given : http://share.ez.no/forums/extensions/ez-flow/get-ez-flow-zones-of-an-object

Comment: I know, that was me. But the eZ Flow Subforum seems to be not really active. So I had more hope getting an answer by asking on stackoverflow, too.

Comment: It appears the eZ Community forums brought a reply : http://share.ez.no/forums/extensions/ez-flow/get-ez-flow-zones-of-an-object/comment69537 :)